# Find the function $f$ such that $f(x)=\frac{f(2x)}{x+1}$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I've been trying to find a function with the property
$$f(x)=\frac{f(2x)}{x+1}$$
using elementary functions only, and it has proven to be harder than I thought.

Does anyone know how to go about finding a function given one of its properties in a systematic manner?

I can already guess that this function will use a logarithm (base 2) somewhere in it, but I still can't find the function.

Does it exist in the elementary functions? Does it exist elsewhere? Please help!

Comment: Have you tried Taylor series ?

Comment: Not sure how to use Taylor series to solve this... if you know, can you give me a hint as to how I might use them?

Comment: I don't know it looks a bit like cushy furmula. But first try to take the derivative of both side and on the right hand side you will still have f(x). Then maybe with some algebra it will take you further.

Comment: using Elad's idea : if $f(x)$ can be written as $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n x^n$ then for all $n \geq 1$ one has $(2^n-1)a_n=a_{n-1}$

Comment: *a* function?  Or all functions?  $f(x) = 0;i \ne (-1)2^n$ is of course the simplest.  $f(-1)$ is undefined so so must be $(-1)2^{-n}$.

Comment: "But first try to take the derivative of both side"  Um... no one said anything about it being differentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume $f(0)=1$ we have that a solution of
$$f(x)= \left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) $$
over the interval $x\in(-2,2)$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
 f(x)&=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x}{2^n}\right) \\
&=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{2^n}\right) \\
&=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^m}{m2^{mn}},
\end{align}$$
i.e., by
$$ f(x)=\exp\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^m}{m(2^m-1)}. $$

Comment: Why assuming : $f(0) = 1$ ? Moreover isn't there a link between this FE and the $\Gamma$ function ?

Comment: @J.OK: if you assume something else you get the same solution up to a constant. I do not see any clear connection beween this function and the $\Gamma$ function.